# Has Mathematica 12 gotten worse at solving simple equations?

Tags: equation-solving

Mathematica used to be easily able to solve an equation like this:

```
Reduce[Log[Sqrt[k p]/Log[k]] == 0, p]
```

(I can easily do it myself, at least I can find the solution `p = log(k)^2/k`.)

Now in Mathematica 12, all I get is `Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.`

I thought it might be an issue with assumptions, so I tried assuming both `k` and `p` were sufficiently large, but it didn't help.

Is there a way to get Mathematica 12 to produce useful output on the problem above?

Comment: Works fine with `Solve` instead of `Reduce`. A simpler version of this problem is `Reduce[Sqrt[a x] == b, x]`, which shows how hard this problem is in all generality.

Comment: Fwiw I don't think this is particular to V12. I tried on 11.3 and it gave up there too.

Comment: I still keep my version 9.0.1 although I also have the newest version, but in a way 9.0.1 is the last really stable version.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. See the tag description for why.

Comment: @Roman my version of Mathematica is able to solve `Sqrt[a x] == b` using `Reduce`, though it does complain about the solution containing the "unsolved equation" 0 == b - Sqrt[b^2] as an assumption.

Comment: @ThomasAhle that was my point: it is able to reduce the equation, but complains as you say, and the solution is surprisingly complicated: `(b == 0 && a == 0) || (a != 0 && 0 == b - Sqrt[b^2] && x == b^2/a)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Working only in the real numbers could be a solution:

```
Reduce[Log[Sqrt[k p]/Log[k]] == 0, p, Reals]
(*    k > 1 && p == Log[k]^2/k    *)
```

I think the branch cuts of the square root make this problem difficult to solve in all complex generality ($k\in\mathbb{C}$). Maybe previous versions of *Mathematica* were a bit less careful with these branch cuts? From what I hear there has been a lot of work done in *Mathematica* recently on how to deal with branch cuts.

The given solution $p=\frac{\ln^2k}{k}$ is actually valid for any $\lvert k\rvert>1$, not just for the positive real $k>1$:

```
ComplexPlot3D[Log[Sqrt[k p]/Log[k]] /. p -> Log[k]^2/k,
  {k, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

I guess it would still be nice to find a way to solve/reduce this equation that returns a solution like `Abs[k] > 1 && p == Log[k]^2/k` to show the most general solution.

Comment: Interestingly, while your answer works; `Reduce[Log[Sqrt[k p]/Log[k]] == 0 && Element[{p, k}, Reals], p]` does not.

Comment: @BobHanlon Try  p>0&&k>0 .  The domain Reals  means the variables and functions are assumed to be real.

Comment: @Roman Doesn't the assumptions `k > 0 && p > 0` imply that the variables aren't complex? Adding `Reals` to reduce does the trick though. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasAhle yes, but the term inside the logarithm can still be negative, thereby allowing for cuts. Restricting `k > 1` avoids this scenario and `Reduce` returns a result. Try `Reduce[Log[Sqrt[k p]/Log[k]] == 0 && k > 1 && p > 0, p]`.

Comment: Also read the few lines in the docs starting here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html#26975. Using the domain spec of `Reduce` (its third argument) restricts all values of all function evaluations to be real. Implicitly this means `Reduce[Log[Sqrt[k p]/Log[k]] == 0, p, Reals]` is restricting to `k > 1`.